# How do I test multipart form data requests for file uploads in Play Framework 2.0 using Java?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, functional-testing

I understand that you can do this using the Scala API as suggested here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/play-framework/1vNGW-lPi9I

But there seems to be no way of doing this using Java as only string values are supported in FakeRequests' withFormUrlEncodedBody method?

Is this a missing feature in the API or is there any workaround?  (Using only Java).

Comment: Also looking for an example on how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

For integration testing you can use apache DefaultHttpCLient like I do:

```
@Test
public void addFileItem() throws Exception {
    File testFile = File.createTempFile("test","xml");
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost method = new HttpPost(URL_HOST + "/api/v1/items/file");
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
    entity.addPart("description", new StringBody("This is my file",Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    entity.addPart(Constants.ITEMTYPE_KEY, new StringBody("FILE", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(testFile);
    entity.addPart("file", fileBody);
    method.setEntity(entity);

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(method);             
    assertThat(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(CREATED);
}
```

This requires that you start a server in your tests:

```
public static FakeApplication app;
public static TestServer testServer;

@BeforeClass
public static void startApp() throws IOException {
    app = Helpers.fakeApplication();
    testServer = Helpers.testServer(PORT, app);
    Helpers.start(testServer);

}

@AfterClass
public static void stopApp() {
    Helpers.stop(testServer);
}
```